# pull all data only if there are distinct within a group in SQL

Tags: sql

I have table with the following columns (product ID, product group code, product category)

I only want to pull the data if there there are two or more unique product category data within each product group. for example I have the following data.

```
Product id | product group code | product category
1          | a                  | Apple
2          | a                  | Orange
3          | a                  | Apple
4          | b                  | Toys
5          | b                  | Toys
```

I only want to see all the unique product category for each product code. The output i want to see is:

```
Product id  product group code  product category
1          | a                 |  Apple
2          | a                 |  Orange
3          | a                 |  Apple
```

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

> I only want to pull the data if there there are two or more unique product category data within each product group. for example I have the following data.

This answer is based on the *results* you show which is consistent.  The paragraph before the results is unclear.

One method is `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.product_group = t.product_group and
                    t2.product_category <> t.product_category
             );
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get the result i wanted using exists.

Answer (score 0):

How about two nested selects? one grouping and selecting the group that has more than one in `COUNT DISTINCT product_group_id`, then join the "good group" back to the original input?

```
WITH
-- your input as an in-line table
input(Product_id,product_group_code,product_category) AS (
          SELECT 1,'a','Apple'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'a','Orange'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'a','Apple'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'b','Toys'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'b','Toys'
)
,
good_grp AS (
  SELECT
    product_group_code
  FROM input
  GROUP BY product_group_code
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_category) >1
)
SELECT
  i.*
FROM input i
JOIN good_grp USING(product_group_code)
ORDER BY 1
```

-- returning ...

```
Product_id | product_group_code | product_category 
-----------+--------------------+------------------
         1 | a                  | Apple
         2 | a                  | Orange
         3 | a                  | Apple
```